# is ConstraintLayout support automatically LR and RL by device language in android or not

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

is ConstraintLayout support automatically LR and RL by device  language in android or not

and how make this constraint layout support minimum api is 15 with automatically LR and RL by device  language please help me if you can

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="58dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/TestKey"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
    />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please make a minimum effort on [punctuation](https://thewritecorner.wordpress.com/2009/11/14/the-importance-of-punctuation/), your question is difficult to understand as it stands now.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can replace every 
Right with End & 
Left with Start

```
(e.g. app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf= ...
to app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf=...)
```